# Why expensive headphones sound cheap on Linux - the drivers suck?

Tags: drivers, sound, headphones

I bought some decent headphones - dt770 and was expecting a great sound. But under Linux they sound like cheap ones. It’s not bad, it just not the high quality sound these headphones usually produce.
And I figured out it may be the drivers.
On windows they initially sounded the same. Then I upgraded the drivers to the proper dell ones, not the stock drivers and the difference was huge.
But I can’t do that on Linux.

What I figured is the mid range frequencies are way too high. So I used some pulse audio plugin to carefully tune them a bit - it’s much closer to the windows sound but it’s still not the same.

Is there a solution to this problem? Or is Linux destined to have a bad sound because of the lack of official support by the sound card manufacturers?

Also wound buying an external sound card solve the problem?

Comment: The latter, probably, but then again the end users should choose known good and tested hardware ;)

Comment: Are you hearing any other problems besides the equalization?

Comment: @wjandrea The sound starts clipping sometimes but that’s only after applying my equalizing, even if it barely changes the frequencies. If it’s off - no, I don’t think so. On Windows the drivers have one checkbox - “Audio Enhancement” - that’s what does all the magic. Without it the sound is like the Linux one. As if that checkbox applies some awesome equalization, you get a lot of bass also, yet the sound never clips.

Comment: @MichaelBay if there’s a sound card with proper Linux drivers, I would gladly buy it :)

Comment: Easy. Any one of them except a very few that require special, tweaked and proprietary drivers that incidentally are only available for Windows.

Comment: @MichaelBay seems like all my 3 sound cards, which are actually nothing special, fall into this "very few, windows-only" category.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been able to achieve significant improvement in the sound with some tweaking.

First of all - these problems are only noticable on high end headphones.

What I hear is too much mid range. So I actually hooked up an oscilloscope to the audio port and started looking at what happens - and it does confirm that something very shi*ty is happening.
Every time a certain frequency is played, the output is not only this frequency but there's also a harmonic one at the other end of the spectrum.
20hz wave has a harmonic around 20 khz and the higher you go, the lower the harmonic goes, so around the mid range they meet and amplify.
I guess this is why you can hear so much mids.

So how to improve - obviously get a good EQ plugin for pulseaudio, such as PulseEffects and carefully lower these mids.

Another huge improvement comes from changing the default PulseAudio algorithm.
This is in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf: resample-method

Change to soxr-vhq or speex-float-5

I really don't know how they can spend so much time supporting these algorithms but ship it with the poor one by default, and hiding all information on the topic...

Anyways, enjoy!

Comment: Impressive researching. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using the equalizer (PulseEffects / EasyEffects), I recommend loading my presets: [EasyPulse](https://github.com/p-chan5/EasyPulse) You will notice a big difference in your speakers or headphones.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).